# How to I tell this Applescript to skip some files?

Tags: applescript, handbrake

Im, using an Applescript to bashconvert a whole bunch of mv4 files to 640x480 using Handbrake CLI. I have a applescript I found somewhere changed to my parameters, and it works great. But to save time, I want the script to skip files that are already 640x480, since not all files need conversion. How would I go about that?

Here´s the script:

```
--on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
with timeout of (720 * 60) seconds
tell application "Finder"
    --Get all m4v files that have no label color yet, meaning it hasn’t been processed
    set allFiles to every file of entire contents of ("FIRSTHD:Users:jerry:Desktop:Omkodning" as alias) whose ((name extension is "m4v") and label index is 0)
    --Repeat for all files in above folder
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in allFiles
        set currentFile to (item i of allFiles)
        try
            --Set to gray label to indicate processing
            set label index of currentFile to 7
            --Assemble original and new file paths
            set origFilepath to quoted form of POSIX path of (currentFile as alias)
            set newFilepath to (characters 1 thru -5 of origFilepath as string) & "mp4'"
            --Start the conversion
            set shellCommand to "nice /Applications/HandBrakeCLI -i " & origFilepath & " -o " & newFilepath & " -e ffmpeg4 -b 1200 -a 1 -E faac -B 160 -R 29.97 -f mp4 –crop 0:0:0:0 crf 24 -w 640 -l 480  ;"
            do shell script shellCommand
            --Set the label to green in case file deletion fails
            set label index of currentFile to 6
            --Remove the old file
            set shellCommand to "rm -f " & origFilepath
            do shell script shellCommand
        on error errmsg
            --Set the label to red to indicate failure
            set label index of currentFile to 2
        end try
    end repeat
end tell
end timeout
--end adding folder items to
```

Answer (score 0):

*Edited for clarity....*

Since `HandBreakCLI` doesn't have any options to tell it not to convert if the resolution is 640x480, you have to handle that bit of logic in your script. It is easily done.

So all your script needs to do is...

```
get the video file resolution

If file is not at desired resolution then
    convert the file
else
    skip it
end if
```

So, as [discussed here](https://superuser.com/questions/595177/how-to-retrieve-video-file-information-from-command-line-under-linux), you can use the freely available `mediainfo` command line tool to get the video resolution.

Here is some applescript code which you can copy/paste and run to see how it works...

```
set filterStr to " | grep pixels | tr -d [:alpha:][:blank:][:punct:]"

set allFiles to (choose file with multiple selections allowed)

repeat with i from 1 to number of items in allFiles
    set currentFile to (item i of allFiles)

    set cmdStr to "/usr/local/bin/mediainfo " & ¬
        quoted form of POSIX path of currentFile & filterStr

    set h to 0
    set w to 0
    try
        set fileInfo to do shell script (cmdStr)
        set {w, h} to every paragraph of fileInfo
    end try

    if w is not 640 and h is not 480 then
        log w & " x " & h

        # Convert to desired resolution....
    end if
end repeat
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do rather use handbrakecli and the script i use, works great. Just wanna skip the 640x480'

Comment: You misunderstand. This code is to be used _in_ your script. `handbreakecli` doesn't seem to have the logic to skip. So.... you use the code above instead. The above is an example of how you would use it....

Comment: Thanks again! Understand the logic in it, not sure how to apply it. Installed mediainfo, when I run the scriptexample I get to choose a file, but then nothing seems to happen, should it not output some info? Also unsure how to apply it to the script I use. Thanks for the effort, really appriciate it!

Comment: Sorry but cant help further at the moment. My mac just died and i am left with my iphone - i am using it now to post this. Once it is repaired i will edit my answer further.